# Loop_control index_var in Ansible 2.0

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that is compatible with Ansible 2.6. This playbook uses the `loop_control` module to construct a string.

```
vars:
  app_config:
      attr1    :
      - "1"
      nexatt  :
      - "b"
 ...
- set_fact:
     app_properties: ""

- name: Reading the Specific Configuration
  set_fact:
     app_properties: "{{ app_properties }}{{ (index > 0)|ternary(',','') }}{{ item.key }}={{ item.value[0] }}"
  loop: "{{  app_config|dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: index
```

The string is then passed to a script as an option:

```
- name: Create Configurations
  command: "{{ dir }}/{{ script }}
            {{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ app_properties }}"
```

Is there a way to do this so that it is Ansible 2.0 compatible (given that Ansible 2.0 does not have `loop_control`)?
(I have another setup that requires Ansible 2.0  and needs this playbook. I cannot upgrade to Ansible 2.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a direct equivalent, you can use the with_indexed_items loop construct to iterate over a list along with an index value.  Because the `with_*` loops perform an implicit flattening of their input, you'll need to wrap your list in a list, so that the final playbook looks like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    app_config:
      attr1:
        - "1"
      nexatt:
        - "b"
  tasks:
    - name: Reading the Specific Configuration
      set_fact:
        app_properties: "{{ app_properties|default('') }}{{ (item.0 > 0)|ternary(',','') }}{{ item.1.0 }}={{ item.1.1.0 }}"
      with_indexed_items: ["{{ app_config.items() }}"]

    - debug:
        var: app_properties
```

I've dropped your task that initializes `app_properties` in favor of
using Ansible's `default` filter.

For what you're doing you don't even need to use a loop
index.  For example, if you're willing to live with an additional
`set_fact` task, you could do this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    app_config:
      attr1:
        - "1"
      nexatt:
        - "b"
  tasks:
    - name: Reading the Specific Configuration
      set_fact:
        app_properties_list: "{{ app_properties_list|default([]) + ['%s=%s' % (item.0, item.1.0)] }}"
      with_items: ["{{ app_config.items() }}"]

    - name: Create comma-delimieted app_properties list
      set_fact:
        app_properties: "{{ ','.join(app_properties_list) }}"

    - debug:
        var: app_properties
```

The above will work with Ansible 2.0.0.2 or later (and probably
earlier!). There are probably other ways of tackling this problems as
well (such as a template `{% for %}...{% endfor %}` loop).

Comment: That is phenomenal. Thank you for your help. This is great solution. I like the alternative solution.